# сопоставить 2 массива php

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив городов вида:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [city_id] => 1 [name] => Волгоград ) [4] => Array ( [city_id] => 4 [name] => Краснодар  ) )
```

и есть массив с ID городов доступных для текущего объекта вида:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [city_id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [city_id] => 4 ) )
```

Задача: вывести список городов, напротив каждого города вывести в наличии или нет.

На данный момент мой код имеет такой вид:

```
    <div class="sclad">        
      Доступно на складе:<br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <?php 
          foreach($city_names as $city){
              echo $city['name']."<br>";                  
        }?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <?php foreach($city_list as $p_city) {
          foreach($city_names as $city){
            if($city['city_id'] == $p_city['city_id']){
              echo "<span class='green'>В наличии</span><br>";
            }
            else {
              echo "<span class='red'>Нет в наличии</span><br>";
            }
          }                    
        }?>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Но это уже после долгих попыток и мучений я начал писать какую-то дичь)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите плиз разобраться, заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно без дополнительного цикла проверить это, используйте конструкцию `in_array`

```
<div class="sclad">        
  Доступно на складе:<br>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?php 
      foreach($city_names as $city){
          echo $city['name']."<br>";                  
    }?>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <?foreach($city_names as $city) {
        if(in_array(['city_id' => $city["city_id"]], $city_list)) {
          echo "<span class='green'>В наличии</span><br>";
        }
        else {
          echo "<span class='red'>Нет в наличии</span><br>";
        }
     }?>
  </div>
</div>
```